# How can i shift all rows without giving exception?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a workbook with 4 sheets in it. I cloned the 4th sheet. I'm trying to shift all the data from the new cloned sheet down by 1 row. But when i try the shiftRow in one of my methods, it gives a FormulaParseException. Any help appreciated.

```
public class SanityChecker extends BaseCostSheetCmd { 

String fileName = "C:/Users/.../.xlsx";
File file = new File(fileName);
String vendorFile = "C:/Users/.../.xlsx";

public void initWB() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(is);
    XSSFSheet out = wb.cloneSheet(3, "sanity check");

    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

    is.close();
    wb.write(fs);
    fs.close();
    wb.close(); 
 }

public void addRow(File file, int amount, int currentRow) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(4);
    sheet.shiftRows(currentRow, sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1, amount, true,true);
    is.close();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    workbook.close();
}

@Override
public void process(Matcher m) throws Exception {
    // TODO start here
    initWB();
    addRow(file, 1, 0);
    logln("hello world");
}
```

Exception:

org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Unused input [[[#All],[TRIMMED CAT NUM]:[DISTRIBUTOR MULTIPLIER]]] after attempting to parse the formula [[1]!018128_1634058909268[[#All],[TRIMMED CAT NUM]:[DISTRIBUTOR MULTIPLIER]]]

Comment: According to the error `apache poi` gets confused by a formula using structured references to a table which is in an external workbook. I doubt there is a simple solution except not to use such formulas. But `apache poi` gets further developed very fast. What `apache poi` version are you using? If it is not the last version, try upgrading. Else do post a bug report to `apache poi`.

Comment: im using version 4.0.0. so its kind of old.